# Get highest file path by size in bash where path contains space

Tags: bash

I have alot of subdirectories structure with several mkv files.

I want to retrieve the biggest file by size, I managed to do with (test.sh):

```
$folder="$1"
m2ts=$(find "$folder" -type f -iname *.mkv -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f2)
echo $m2ts
```

All good until if folder might contain space like: `/home/tester/This is a long path`

If I do test:

```
find "/home/tester/This is a long path" -type f -iname *.mkv -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

It returns : `/home/tester/This` instead if biggest mkv path

What should I do ?

Comment: I'm confused, with the options `-type f -iname *.mkv`, how is that returning a directory? Or, are you saying that `/home/tester/This` is the first whitespace separated directory name component for a file that you didn't show, e.g. `/home/tester/This is a long path/tofile.mkv`? `cut` is causing the problem. Use another delimiter in `-printf '%s %p\n'`, e.g. `-printf '%s#%p\n'` (or some other character not part of your filenames that makes an easy delimiter)

Comment: Another reasonable option is the double vertical bar (extended ASCII, decimal `166`, or Unicode point `U + 00A6`), e.g. `'¦'` (note: not the `'|'` (pipe) character)

Comment: All you need is `-f2-` (instead of `-f2`) in `cut` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that by specifying `cut -d ' '` you tell `cut` to split fields at every space character. So if your path contains a space, it will be cut off.
One simple solution would be:

```bash
$folder="$1"
m2ts=$(find "$folder" -type f -iname *.mkv -printf '%s\t%p\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f2-)
echo $m2ts
```

Note how `printf '%s %p\n'` was replaced with `printf '%s\t%p\n'`,
which allows us to use the default field separator in `cut` (the tab character `'\t'`).

Additionally, by specifying `cut -f2-` instead of `cut -f2`,
we get *all* fields after the size, not just up to the next field separator (`\t`). So even if the filepath would contain a tab, it would still work.

If some lunatic decides to use newlines in their file names this will still break, but at that point they just want to see the world burn :).

Comment: Congrats on reaching 1K rep `:)`

Comment: It will be safer to say `cut -f2-` than `cut -f2` for the case the filename
contains a tab character. It may be a corner case but worth considering.